# How to consolidate overlap date in single

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

How would I get one row out of two overlaping dates rows from the same table for same id. I have more then 50000 records.

I have following sample data.

```
ID    start_dt    end_dt       division
1212  04/01/2006  03/01/2007   second
1212  05/01/2009  01/01/2010   second
1212  04/01/2006  03/01/2008   second   --- This should be selected as longest timeframe
1212  09/03/2007  03/01/2008   third
1213  05/03/2005  04/11/2009   second
1214  07/03/2007  03/01/2008   third
```

And the data I should get as following.

```
ID    start_dt    end_dt       division
1212  04/01/2006  03/01/2008   second
1212  05/01/2009  01/01/2010   second
1213  05/03/2005  04/11/2009   second
1214  07/03/2007  03/01/2008   third
```

Thank you.
Ramu

Comment: let me guess... if it was allowed, you'd have slapped on more database tags for Access, DB2, Informix, PostGres, FoxPro, etc...?  We're not here to do your job for you. Such a query is utterly basic SQL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand your issue, just subtract the 2 dates to determine the time frame difference:

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Start_dt, S.End_dt, S.Division
FROM Sample S
 JOIN (
   SELECT S.Id, Max(S.end_dt-S.start_dt) as timeframe
FROM Sample S
GROUP BY S.Id ) S2 ON S.Id = S2.Id 
    AND S.end_dt-S.start_dt = s2.timeframe
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91076/2).

Good luck.

Comment: Well with rownum we get only specific row but as I mentioned there is morethen one or two record exist for the same id. And we get only the largest timeframe one. Sorry I will modify the data.

Comment: Hi sgeddes, there is no DateDiff function in Oracle. :(

Comment: Hi sgeddes, thanks that give me only which overlap one but i am not getting the data which is outside of the overlapping for the same id. let me add one more data example.